# how to inject.table td properties from bootstrap.css

Tags: css

In standard bootstrap.css there is:

```
.table th,
.table td {
  border: 0.5px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

but my jsp's td does not see it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><jsp:include page="header.jsp" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><jsp:include page="menu.jsp" /></td>
        <td><jsp:include page="../${contentPage}.jsp" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

to get the css properties for td I must change bootstrap.css to:

```
td {
  border: 0.5px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

Can anyone explain me how to use this bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

See how the bootstrap css has the period before table?  This means it's for the 'table' class, not all the table elements.  You need to add the 'table' class to your table element like this 
`<table class="table">`.